# I have written code but when i call average() function after defining and passing argument got error

Tags: python

I have passed argument to a function but when i call average() to display the output i got an error.

```py
def average(num1, num2, num3):
    sum = num1 + num2 + num3
    avg = sum / 3
    print(average)
average(100, 90, 92)
average()  # why can't i call
```

average()
TypeError: average() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'num1', 'num2', and 'num3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`average()` doesn't display the output, but instead you're telling python to call the function again. However, this second time you don't pass any arguments between the brackets, which is why you get the 'missing 3 required arguments' error.

If you want to print the result of `average(100, 90, 92)`, try calling only that without the final line of code.

---

Also, IMO it is better practice to use `return avg` - and then when you call the function, you use `print(average(100, 90, 92)` - instead of having the `print(avg)` inside your function.

This is helpful as you code will get increasingly complex. You'll not just be able to print out the average, but also store its result in a variable that you can manipulate later on in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You used `average()` without adding the 3 arguments. remove the last line of code (`average()`). Also in your print statement, replace `average` by `avg`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this section of code is being used.  One way around this is to have the numbers to a list?

```
def average(numbers): 
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers) 

numbers = [100, 90, 92] 
average_number = average(list) 
print(average_number)
```